# How do I type a Chinese dash in XeLaTex

Tags: symbols, punctuation, languages, unicode

How do I write a Chinese dash, a two-fullwidth-character long dash?

「——」 looks ugly typset with XeLaTex and the font that I am using (The two parts are not connected and there is a gap in the middle).  I guess I could use some drawing tool and draw a line at the right hight.  But how do I make the line exactly 2 fullwidht characters long?

Comment: Does the font you are using contain the character? If so you can just enter it directly into your source. Is it just the regular em dash? (Typed in LaTeX usually as `---`?) If so, you need to load your font with `[Ligatures=TeX]` to have `--` and `---` work as they would in a regular LaTeX document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get additional information on how to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 8):

This depends on the font, If I use SimSun (as I had used it in a previous answer) I see no gap if I use the input you show (2 em dashes) I do see a gap if I use the classic TeX input `------` Unicode 6.1 introduces U+2E3A (TWO-EM DASH) but that might be a bit new to be in commonly distributed fonts, I get no visible character in that slot). Sorry about the probably out of context characters: I borrowed them from the previous question, just to check I had loaded a CJK font correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{ctexbook}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}


\begin{document}

本条------本条

本条——本条

本条⸺本条

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by creating a new macro that "draws" the dash I want.

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\chinesedash}{\rule[.7ex]{\widthof{二字}}{0.5pt}}
```